# Multiple Resolution Support in Cocos2d-x v2.2.5 in Portrait mode

Tags: cocos2d-x, screen-resolution

I am working on a game in cocos2d-x which is in portrait mode.

Now, for a long time now, I've been working on how to properly achieve multi resolution in cocos2d-x but failed. I followed this [great tutorial](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Multi_resolution_support) on forum, but it wasn't enough, I also searched a lot but couldn't find a solution.

I also tried with different-different policies which are available with cocos-x.

I went through all the following links & tutorials

Using these links I could achieve for all ios resolutions but not for all android screens.

- http://becomingindiedev.blogspot.in/2014/05/multi-resolution-support-in-ios-with.html
- http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/porting-ios-game-to-android-multi-resolution-suppor/5260/5
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CH9Ct4R0nBM
- https://github.com/SonarSystems/Cocos2d-x-v3-C---Tutorial-4---Multi-Resolution-Support

I even tried with newer version of cocos2d-x, but they also not providing anything which can support both ios and android screens.

Comment: Have you tried using CCDevice::getDPI(). It gives pixels per inch. If you need your objects to be displayed in the same physical dimension in all devices you can use this value to resize, positioning etc..

Comment: hmm okey , i will try with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working for me this way for Portrait mode:

**Below the header :**

```
typedef struct tagResource
{

     cocos2d::CCSize size;
     char directory[100];

} Resource;

static Resource smallResource   =  { cocos2d::CCSizeMake(640, 960),"iPhone" };

static Resource mediumResource  =  { cocos2d::CCSizeMake(768, 1024),"iPad"};

static Resource largeResource   =  { cocos2d::CCSizeMake(1536, 2048),"iPadhd" };

static cocos2d::CCSize designResolutionSize = cocos2d::CCSizeMake(768, 1024);
```

**in applicationDidFinishLaunching() method :**

```
 // initialize director

    CCDirector* pDirector = CCDirector::sharedDirector();
    CCEGLView* pEGLView = CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView();

    pDirector->setOpenGLView(pEGLView);


    CCSize frameSize = pEGLView->getFrameSize();

    std::vector<std::string> searchPaths;

    // Set the design resolution


    pEGLView->setDesignResolutionSize(designResolutionSize.width, designResolutionSize.height, kResolutionExactFit);

    if (frameSize.height <= smallResource.size.height)
    {
        searchPaths.push_back(mediumResource.directory);      
        CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->setSearchPaths(searchPaths);    

    pDirector->setContentScaleFactor(mediumResource.size.height/designResolutionSize.height);

    }
    else if (frameSize.height <= mediumResource.size.height)
    {
        searchPaths.push_back(mediumResource.directory);
        CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->setSearchPaths(searchPaths);
    pDirector->setContentScaleFactor(mediumResource.size.height/designResolutionSize.height);
    }
    else
    {
        searchPaths.push_back(largeResource.directory);
        CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->setSearchPaths(searchPaths);
    pDirector->setContentScaleFactor(largeResource.size.height/designResolutionSize.height);

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following bit of code in my AppDelegate:

```
void AppDelegate::multiresolutionSupport()
{
    auto director = Director::getInstance();
    auto glview = director->getOpenGLView();

    cocos2d::Size designSize = cocos2d::Size(320, 480);
    cocos2d::Size resourceSize = cocos2d::Size(320, 480);
    cocos2d::Size screenSize = glview->getFrameSize();

    float margin1 = (320 + 640) / 2;
    float margin2 = (768 + 1536) / 2;

    if (screenSize.width < margin1) {
        FileUtils::getInstance()->addSearchResolutionsOrder("SD");
    } else if (480 <= screenSize.width && screenSize.width < margin2) {
        FileUtils::getInstance()->addSearchResolutionsOrder("HD");
        designSize = cocos2d::Size(screenSize.width / 2, screenSize.height / 2);
    } else {
        FileUtils::getInstance()->addSearchResolutionsOrder("HDR");
        designSize = cocos2d::Size(screenSize.width / 4, screenSize.height / 4);
    }

    resourceSize = screenSize;

    director->setContentScaleFactor(resourceSize.width / designSize.width);
    glview->setDesignResolutionSize(designSize.width, designSize.height, ResolutionPolicy::NO_BORDER);
}
```

Call it before loading any assets and you should have it working properly. I call it right after my glview is created in AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching().

How it works:

- it uses a bunch of magic numbers to determine (roughly) what texture
  resolution should we use: SD(@1), HD(@2) or HDR(@4) and then adjusts
  design size accordingly, by dividing it on the content scale factor
- it adds appropriate search paths to FileUtils it sets design
- resolution and content scale factor for the engine

Answer (score 0):

We are the team who made the multi resolution tutorial for the github link, it does support Android but the folders are just named using iOS naming conventions thats all.

Hope this helps.

Regards
Sonar Systems